# Type Casting of class functions in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, casting

I'm using Symfony and Doctrine and I need to compare if an object from JSON has the same attribute than one in the database.

So I've done everything correctly but as I'm new to PHP I can't access the attributes of my object because I don't know how to cast the previous line to a Product.

```
$oldProduct = new Product();
$oldProduct = $repo->findBy( array('nom' => $product->getNom()));
$oldProduct->
```

I tried adding

```
$oldProduct = Product::$repo->findBy( array('nom' => $product->getNom()));
```

but that doesn't work

I'm sure it has already been answered but I can't find the keywords to get a similar problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really understand your question.. What has checking values to do with type casting?

Comment: well I thought that auto completion not showing would give me an error when compiling but it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force type casting by adding:

```
$oldProduct = $repo->findBy(array('nom' => $product->getNom()));
/* @var Product $oldProduct */
$oldProduct->myAutoCompletedFunction...
```

Or:

```
$oldProduct = $repo->findBy(array('nom' => $product->getNom()));
if (!$oldProduct instanceof Product) {
    throw new \LogicException('Old product not found.');
}
$oldProduct->myAutoCompletedFunction...
```

The second version is better because it doesn't raise warning for static analyzers.

**PS**: Note that you can put the block containing the `@var` comment at the end of the first line instead of having a line for it.